# array, std::list, std::vector inserting time

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I am making a test program to measure time for storage of each container. The following is my code for the test.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void insert(list<short>& l, const short& value);
void insert(vector<short>& v, const short& value);
void insert(short arr[], int& logicalSize, const int& physicalSize, const short& value);

int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    srand(time(nullptr));

    const int SIZE = 50000;
    const short RANGE = 10000;
    list<short> l;
    vector<short> v;
    short* arr = new short[SIZE];
    int logicalSize = 0;

    // array
    start = clock();
    cout << "Array storage time test...";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        try {
            insert(arr, logicalSize, SIZE, (short)(rand() % (2 * RANGE + 1) - RANGE));
        } catch (string s) {
            cout << s << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time: " << difftime(end, start) << endl << endl;

    // list
    cout << "List storage time test...";
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        insert(l, (short)(rand() % (2 * RANGE + 1) - RANGE));
    }
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time: " << difftime(end, start) << endl << endl;

    // vector
    cout << "Vector storage time test...";
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        insert(v, (short)(rand() % (2 * RANGE + 1) - RANGE));
    }
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time: " << difftime(end, start) << endl << endl;



    delete[] arr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void insert(list<short>& l, const short& value) {
    for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
        if (value < *it) {
            l.insert(it, value);
            return;
        }
    }
    l.push_back(value);
}

void insert(vector<short>& v, const short& value) {
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        if (value < *it) {
            v.insert(it, value);
            return;
        }
    }
    v.push_back(value);
}

void insert(short arr[], int& logicalSize, const int& physicalSize, const short& value) {
    if (logicalSize == physicalSize) throw string("No spaces in array.");
    for (int i = 0; i < logicalSize; i++) {
        if (value < arr[i]) {
            for (int j = logicalSize - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[i] = value;
            logicalSize++;
            return;
        }
    }
    arr[logicalSize] = value;
    logicalSize++;
}
```

However, when I execute the code, the result seems a little different from the theory. The list should be fastest, but the result said that insertion in the list is slowest. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Hope you are compiling with the optimization flags enabled!

Comment: In your array test replace the loop with `memmove(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1], logicalSize - i);` It will make it twice as fast.

Comment: Small fix: `memmove(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1], (logicalSize - i) * sizeof(short))`

Answer (score 2):

Inserting into a vector or array requires moving everything after it; so if at a random spot, requires an average of 1.5 accesses to each element.  0.5 to find the spot, and 0.5*2 (read and write) to do the insert.

Inserting into a list requires 0.5 accesses per element (to find the spot).

This means the vector is only 3 times more element accesses.

Lists nodes are 5 to 9 times larger than vector "nodes" (which are just elements).  Forward iteration requires reading 3 to 5 times as much memory (element 16 bits and pointer 32 to 64 bits).

So the list solution reads/writes more memory!  Worse, it is sparser (with the back pointer), *and* it may not be arranged in a cache-friendly way in memory (vectors are contiguous; list nodes may be a mess in linear space) thus messing with cpu memory cache predictions and loads and etc.

List is very rarely faster than vector; you have to be inserting/deleting many times more often than you iterate over the list.

Finally vector uses exponential allocation with reserved unused space.  List allocates each time.  Calling `new` is slow, and often not much slower when you ask for bigger chunks than when you ask for smaller ones.  Growing a vector by 1 at a time 1000 times results in about 15 allocations (give or take); for list, 1000 allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion in a `list` is blisteringly fast, but first you have to find there you want to insert. This is where `list` comes out a loser.

It might be helpful to stop and read [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) sometime around now because it covers similar material and covers it really well.

With a `vector` or array each element comes one after the next. Prediction is dead easy, so the CPU can be loading the cache with values you won't need for a while at the same time as it is processing the current value.

With a `list` predictability is shot, you have to get the next node before you can load the node after that, and that pretty much nullifies the cache. [Without the cache you can see an order of magnitude degradation in performance](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) as the CPU sits around waiting for data to be retrieved from RAM.

[Bjarne Stroustrup has a number of longer pieces on this topic](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists). The keynote video is definitely worth watching.

One important take-away is take Big-O notation with a grain of salt because it is measuring a the efficiency of the algorithm, not how well the algorithm takes advantage of the hardware.